# how to create a group ID based on 5 minutes interval in pandas timeseries?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I have a timeseries dataframe  `df` looks like this (the time seris happen within same day, but across different hours:

```
                                id               val 
 time                    
2014-04-03 16:01:53             23              14389      
2014-04-03 16:01:54             28              14391             
2014-04-03 16:05:55             24              14393             
2014-04-03 16:06:25             23              14395             
2014-04-03 16:07:01             23              14395             
2014-04-03 16:10:09             23              14395             
2014-04-03 16:10:23             26              14397             
2014-04-03 16:10:57             26              14397             
2014-04-03 16:11:10             26              14397
```

I need to create group every 5 minutes from starting from `16:00:00`. That is all the rows with in the range `16:00:00` to `16:05:00`, its value of the new column `period` is 1. (the number of rows within each group is irregular, so i can't simply cut the group)

Eventually, the data should look like this:

```
                                id               val           period 
time            
2014-04-03 16:01:53             23              14389             1
2014-04-03 16:01:54             28              14391             1
2014-04-03 16:05:55             24              14393             2
2014-04-03 16:06:25             23              14395             2
2014-04-03 16:07:01             23              14395             2
2014-04-03 16:10:09             23              14395             3
2014-04-03 16:10:23             26              14397             3
2014-04-03 16:10:57             26              14397             3
2014-04-03 16:11:10             26              14397             3
```

The purpose is to perform some `groupby` operation, but the operation I need to do is not included in `pd.resample(how=' ')` method. So I have to create a `period` column to identify each group, then do `df.groupby('period').apply(myfunc)`.

Any help or comments are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what about `df['period'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5Min'))['val'].transform(np.mean)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `TimeGrouper` function in a `groupy/apply`. With a `TimeGrouper` you don't need to create your period column. I know you're not trying to compute the mean but I will use it as an example:

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5Min'))['val'].mean()

time
2014-04-03 16:00:00    14390.000000
2014-04-03 16:05:00    14394.333333
2014-04-03 16:10:00    14396.500000
```

Or an example with an explicit `apply`:

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5Min'))['val'].apply(lambda x: len(x) > 3)

time
2014-04-03 16:00:00    False
2014-04-03 16:05:00    False
2014-04-03 16:10:00     True
```

Doctstring for `TimeGrouper`:

```
Docstring for resample:class TimeGrouper@21

TimeGrouper(self, freq = 'Min', closed = None, label = None,
how = 'mean', nperiods = None, axis = 0, fill_method = None,
limit = None, loffset = None, kind = None, convention = None, base = 0,
**kwargs)

Custom groupby class for time-interval grouping

Parameters
----------
freq : pandas date offset or offset alias for identifying bin edges
closed : closed end of interval; left or right
label : interval boundary to use for labeling; left or right
nperiods : optional, integer
convention : {'start', 'end', 'e', 's'}
    If axis is PeriodIndex

Notes
-----
Use begin, end, nperiods to generate intervals that cannot be derived
directly from the associated object
```

**Edit**

I don't know of an elegant way to create the period column, but the following will work:

```
>>> new = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5Min'),as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x['val'])
>>> df['period'] = new.index.get_level_values(0)
>>> df

                     id    val  period
time
2014-04-03 16:01:53  23  14389       0
2014-04-03 16:01:54  28  14391       0 
2014-04-03 16:05:55  24  14393       1
2014-04-03 16:06:25  23  14395       1
2014-04-03 16:07:01  23  14395       1
2014-04-03 16:10:09  23  14395       2
2014-04-03 16:10:23  26  14397       2
2014-04-03 16:10:57  26  14397       2
2014-04-03 16:11:10  26  14397       2
```

It works because the groupby here with as_index=False actually returns the period column you want as the part of the multiindex and I just grab that part of the multiindex and assign to a new column in the orginal dataframe. You could do anything in the apply, I just want the index:

```
>>> new

   time
0  2014-04-03 16:01:53    14389
   2014-04-03 16:01:54    14391
1  2014-04-03 16:05:55    14393
   2014-04-03 16:06:25    14395
   2014-04-03 16:07:01    14395
2  2014-04-03 16:10:09    14395
   2014-04-03 16:10:23    14397
   2014-04-03 16:10:57    14397
   2014-04-03 16:11:10    14397

>>>  new.index.get_level_values(0)

Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know this `TimeGrouper` thing. I got the idea. But if I have to create this new colum `period`, do you have a way to do it? I am thinking to use `,groupby(grouper).transoform(func)` create the period column, but I can't think of a function to do that.

Comment: By the way, why can't I find `pd.TimeGrouper` in the pandas doc? Could you please give a link so that I can learned different strategies?

Comment: Yeah, there isn't much on it in the docs; I will add the docstring to my answer.

Comment: Adding your group column isn't super easy (well, maybe there is an easy way to do it but it's not obvious to me). I'll add how to do that to my answer when I get a chance though.

Comment: Thanks! I did it in a silly way by looping over groups then add the column to groups, and last concat the groups...

Comment: I added a non-looping way to do it, but it's not elegant.

Comment: @KarlD. use cumcount() on the groupby

Comment: @Jeff cumcount gives you different numbers within group, right? That can't be a group ID

Comment: thought that was what you wanted to count within. the group

Comment: @Jeff, no I just want to create a new column to identify group.

Comment: Is there any way to do a groupby within a groupby, other than looping over groups of the first group by

Comment: Yes, you can do it in an apply. Just do a groupby in a function that the first groupby/apply calls

Comment: `pd.TimeGrouper` has been [depracted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45156301/940592). Use `pd.Grouper` now.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your doing if I understand the question right can be done a lot more easily just using the resample method

```
#Get some data
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2013-01-01 00:00', end='2013-01-31 00:00', freq='min')
a = np.random.randint(20, high=30, size=(len(index),1))
b = np.random.randint(14440, high=14449, size=(len(index),1))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((a,b), axis=1), index=index, columns=['id','val'])
df.head()


Out[34]:
                     id  val
2013-01-01 00:00:00  20  14446
2013-01-01 00:01:00  25  14443
2013-01-01 00:02:00  25  14448
2013-01-01 00:03:00  20  14445
2013-01-01 00:04:00  28  14442

#Define function for variance
import numpy as np
def pyfun(X):

    if X.shape[0] <= 1:
        result = nan

    else:    
        total = 0
        for x in X:
            total = total + x
        mean = float(total) / X.shape[0]

        total = 0
        for x in X:
            total = total + (mean-x)**2
        result = float(total) / (X.shape[0]-1)

    return result

#Try it out
df.resample('5min', how=pyfun)


Out[53]:
                     id val
2013-01-01 00:00:00  12.3    5.7
2013-01-01 00:05:00  9.3     7.3
2013-01-01 00:10:00  4.7     0.8
2013-01-01 00:15:00  10.8    10.3
2013-01-01 00:20:00  11.5    1.5
```

Well that was easy. This is for your own functions but if you want to use a function from a library then all you need to do is specify the function in the how keyword

```
df.resample('5min', how=np.var).head()


Out[54]:
                     id val
2013-01-01 00:00:00  12.3    5.7
2013-01-01 00:05:00  9.3     7.3
2013-01-01 00:10:00  4.7     0.8
2013-01-01 00:15:00  10.8    10.3
2013-01-01 00:20:00  11.5    1.5
```

Comment: The top half of this answer seems unnecessary (or at least the bottom half way more useful - the correct answer to this question)!