# Pandas select date/time interval

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe containing an a value related to an interval a date/time belongs to.
The intervals need to be changed to allow for different analysis of the data.
A sample of the dataframe is as follows, but the original file is about 50k rows (and there are many files to process in this manner):

```
                     Coaster1  Coaster2  Coaster3         Epoch
nDateTime                                                      
2015-09-22 12:32:10         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:11         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:11         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:12         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:12         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:13         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:13         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:14         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:14         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:15         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:15         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:16         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:17         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:17         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
2015-09-22 12:32:17         0         1         0  1.442925e+09
```

The desired output would include a new column 'block', computed by 5 second intervals (for this example) from either the index (nDateTime) or the Epoch timestamp.   The data has been sorted in ascending order by Epoch, but there are many instances where the number of samples is not fixed, thus, a fixed "row chunks" size can't be stablished.

Is there a pythonic & pandas suitable way to do this?

Example desired output:

```
                    Coaster1  Coaster2  Coaster3         Epoch  block
nDateTime                                                             
2015-09-22 12:32:10         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:11         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:11         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:12         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:12         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:13         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:13         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:14         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:14         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:15         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:15         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      1
2015-09-22 12:32:16         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      2
2015-09-22 12:32:17         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      2
2015-09-22 12:32:17         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      2
2015-09-22 12:32:17         0         1         0  1.442925e+09      2
```

Thanks for looking at this and your help!

Comment: Please see edit in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23966229/2901002).

Comment: Thank Jezrael and Alberto! That seems to do it.  Should I close/cancel this question if it is?