# pandas create group ID on a five 5 minutes base

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like below:

```
s = pd.DataFrame({
    'X':np.arange(2, 10),
    'time':pd.to_datetime([
        '20130101 7:34:04', '20130101 8:34:08', '20130101 10:34:08',
        '20130101 12:34:15', '20130101 13:34:28', '20130101 12:34:54',
        '20130101 14:34:55', '20130101 17:29:12'])
})
```

I want to create a group ID for column `time` on an hourly or whatever time interval one ever wants. Let's use hourly basis as an example, below is what I want(starting from midnight 00:00:00):

```
X                time  time-group
0  2 2013-01-01 07:34:04           7
1  3 2013-01-01 08:34:08           8
2  4 2013-01-01 10:34:08          10
3  5 2013-01-01 12:34:15          12
4  6 2013-01-01 13:34:28          13
5  7 2013-01-01 12:34:54          12
6  8 2013-01-01 14:34:55          14
7  9 2013-01-01 17:29:12          17
```

How to do this in an efficient way?

**P.S.** I know in this particular case,  I can just use the `s.time.dt.hour` as `time-group`, but I want a general solution that could work for any time interval.

Comment: do you need to create a new column or are you just trying to group and perform some agg on the group?

Comment: `.dt.floor()` will work for most arbitrary time buckets. Or `pd.cut`

Comment: @Chris, I need to create a  new column. This solution here does not work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966152/how-to-create-a-group-id-based-on-5-minutes-interval-in-pandas-timeseries

Comment: @JasonGoal I believe TimeGrouper was changed to `pd.Group()` did you try `s.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='H'))['X'].sum()`

Comment: I Tried but this still can not give me a new group ID column

Comment: @JasonGoal the example seems to work fine for me...

Comment: @JasonGoal let's continue the conversation in a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184522/chat-with-jasongoal-question-53549378)

Answer (score 0):

With great help from Chris, we figured a solution to this problem, the basic is the same as [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966152/how-to-create-a-group-id-based-on-5-minutes-interval-in-pandas-timeseries), but with a bit modification to start from a base that one wants, the trick here is to add the base(starting point) as the first row of one's `data.frame`
Here are codes；

```
s = pd.DataFrame({
    'X':np.arange(1,10),
    'time':pd.to_datetime([
        '20130101 00:00:00',
        '20130101 7:34:04', '20130101 8:34:08', '20130101 10:34:08',
        '20130101 12:34:15', '20130101 13:34:28', '20130101 12:34:54',
        '20130101 14:34:55', '20130101 17:29:12']),
    'time-group':[1,7,8,10,12,13,12,14,17]
})
# '20130101 00:00:00' is the base I want, you can change it to whatever you want.
s.sort_values(['time'], ascending=[True],inplace=True)
new = s.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='15T'), as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x['time'])
s['time-group'] = new.index.get_level_values(0)
```

Which  will give you:

```
   X                time  time-group
0  1 2013-01-01 00:00:00           0
1  2 2013-01-01 07:34:04          30
2  3 2013-01-01 08:34:08          34
3  4 2013-01-01 10:34:08          42
4  5 2013-01-01 12:34:15          50
5  6 2013-01-01 13:34:28          50
6  7 2013-01-01 12:34:54          54
7  8 2013-01-01 14:34:55          58
8  9 2013-01-01 17:29:12          69
```

Comment: One correction... you need to sort on level(1) before you get the level values for 0...`new.sort_index(level=1).index.get_level_values(0)` that is why index 5 and 6 are incorrect. Your time column is not sorted before you group.